# Encountered error when making external API call in Next.js API Route

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, next.js

I'm writing an API route in next.js that will call GitHub API and return my user with GitHub's response. My API is essentially a proxy.
However, my server in the terminal is crashing with `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`. What am I doing wrong? Appreciate your help, thanks!

```
const https = require('https')

export default (req, res) => {
  const options = {
    host: 'api.github.com',
    path: '/search/repositories?q=tetris',
    headers: {'user-agent': 'gohyifan'}
  }
  https.get(options, (ghRes) => {
    ghRes.on('data', (d) => {
      res.json(d);
    });
  }).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with axios and it worked. Thread can be closed.

```js
const axios = require('axios');

async function handler(req, res) {
  const response = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris');
  if (response) {
    res.json(response.data);
  } else {
    res.json({});
  }
}

export default handler;
```